# Apply function (stat test) to subsets of data for each factor level

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I've looked through many similar questions but not found anything that has helped me solve my problem.

Say I have a data frame dat created like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=rep(c("a","a","b","b"),3), v2=c(rep("x",4),rep("y",4),rep("z",4)), dv=sample(1:100, 12), id=rep(c("p1","p2"),6))
```

...that looks like this:

```
        v1 v2 dv id
    1   a  x 40 p1
    2   a  x 99 p2
    3   b  x 67 p1
    4   b  x 24 p2
    5   a  y 16 p1
    6   a  y 51 p2
    7   b  y 85 p1
    8   b  y 72 p2
    9   a  z 33 p1
    10  a  z 31 p2
    11  b  z 88 p1
    12  b  z 50 p2
```

I would like, for each condition/level of var2, to conduct a t test for difference between conditions a&b of var1. 
I could do this by subsetting the data frame by level of var2 and then looping through applying the t test for diff between conditions a & b of var1, but as I understand it one of the strengths of R is avoiding loops (using apply and other related functions).

(Then I would of course correct for multiple comparisons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that you have is the so-called `apply`-family.

First you split your data up into the different `v1`s, then you apply a function to all subsets.

Given that you want to conduct the t.test on the variable "dv" the approach would like this:

```
split_dat <- split(dat, dat$v2)

sapply(split_dat, function(sub_dat) {
  result <- t.test(sub_dat[sub_dat$v1 == "a", "dv"],
                   sub_dat[sub_dat$v1 == "b", "dv"])

  return(result$p.value)
})

# Result:
#         x         y         z 
# 0.1220663 0.6092622 0.8887763
```